# IMAX and Aspect Ratio

Tags: imax, aspect-ratio

I understand that in most standard 35mm film the choice of filming in either a 2.4:1 AR or a 1.85:1 AR is up to the director.

With that being said, very recently there's been some [IMAX commercials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9A3yTEdja0) popping up about IMAX films being shown with a 1.89:1 AR as having no black bars and 26% more image. So my questions are as follows:

1. Does 1.89:1 make that much of a difference compared to 1.85:1?
2. Is it only possible in an IMAX theater to alternate between aspect ratios or can a director decide to alternate between 1.85:1 and 2.4:1 in a regular theater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging,

1 - There's A difference. It's not that substantial but it shows per the trailer above.

2 - It's entirely up to the director, although according the IMAX, IMAX featured films usualy go full-screen ONLY in IMAX. Meaning the others are left with the regular black-barred 2.4:1.